# Azure: plot without labels

Tags: r, plot, label, azure-machine-learning-service

Suppose I have a dataframe (myDataframe) with two column of values (third and fourth). I want to plot them in a bi-dimensional graph. If I do it in R it works, but it returns me a graph without labels when I run the script from Azure Machine Learning. Someone with ideas?

```
...
plot(myDataframe[,3],myDataframe[,4], 
       main="my title",
       xlab= "x"
       ylab= "y",
       col= "blue", pch = 19, cex = 0.1, lty = "solid", lwd = 2)

# lines(x,y=x, col="yellow")

# add LABELS
text(DF_relativo[,A], DF_relativo[,B], 
       labels=DF_relativo$names, cex= 0.7, pos=2)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using ggplot2() in AzureML is bit different. It can use to have plots with labels. Here's the [Cortana Intelligence gallery example](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/b1c26728eb6c4e4d80dddceae992d653) for the particular task.